# Get all combinations of Array elements in JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, combinations

I have an array of words

`var word_array = ['I','have','a','television']`

I need all the combinations of this array something like this

`var combination = ['I', 'have', 'a', 'television', 'I have', 'a television', 'have a', 'a television', 'television I', 'have I', 'a have', 'a I', 'televsion a'....]`

and the important thing is even if I have more elements in my word array, the combination array should only contain 1, 2, 3 and 4 word combinations.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
var array = ['I','have','a','television', 'hellow', 'how', 'are', 'you'];
var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j < 5; j++) {
  results.push(`${array[i]} ${array[j]}`);
  }
 }

 alert(results);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/xdo2n7kL/11/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but I dont have 1, 2, 3 and 4 word combinations in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer... posting it here so that it might be useful for others like me. Thanks for reading

```js
for (var i = 0; i < my_text.length; i++) {

  for (var b = 0; b < my_text.length; b++) {

    if (i == b) {

      combination.push($.trim(my_text[i] + " "));
    } else {
      combination.push($.trim(my_text[i] + ' ' + my_text[b] + " "));
    }

  }

}
```